# C# Selenium always returns the same object

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hey guys i have a problem with selenium what i do is:

navigate to a page with support tickets, switch to the iframe which shows those, find the container of all the ticket items (XPath "//*[@id='task_table']/tbody") and then select all the entries in the list of tickets (XPath "//*[contains(@id, 'row_task_')]")

now the problem: i'm iterating trough the list of 20 items i got back (tried with foreach loop also) to select subelements of those entries, to get the ticket number for example, which **works for the first item**, but **after that always gives back the same values as in the first item** - if i **print the innerHTML or Text** of the whole element however, i see that the **correct element is selected**, holding the corresponding values in the element.

can someone tell me why i'm always getting the same values from the fist element in the list?

```
private void grabTicketData()
{
    var docUrl = @"https://it4you.xyz/task_list_do#someParameters";

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");

    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); //  chromeOptions
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(docUrl);

    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(10000);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

    driver.SwitchTo().Frame("gsft_main");
    var webAppIframe = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='task_table']/tbody"));
    var elements = webAppIframe.FindElements(By.XPath(@"//*[contains(@id, 'row_task_')]"));

    var newLstTickets = new ObservableCollection<Ticket>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= (elements.Count - 1); i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(elements[i].Text);
        //var itemInnerHtml = elements[i].GetAttribute("innerHTML");


        var Id = elements[i].FindElement(By.XPath("//td[3]/a")).Text;
        var Prio = elements[i].FindElement(By.XPath("//td[4]")).Text;
        var Status = elements[i].FindElement(By.XPath("//td[5]")).Text;
        var DelegatedTo = elements[i].FindElement(By.XPath("//td[7]")).Text;
        var Subject = elements[i].FindElement(By.XPath("//td[8]")).Text;
        var Type = elements[i].FindElement(By.XPath("//td[9]")).Text;

        Debug.WriteLine("#####ID:" + Id + " ---- Prio:" + Prio + " -- Status:" + Status + " - DelegatedTo:" + DelegatedTo + " - Subject:" + Subject + " - Type:" + Type);

        newLstTickets.Add(new Ticket(Id, Prio, Status, DelegatedTo, Subject, Type));
    }

    driver.Quit();
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, i got it working, kinda confused why this is this way but it works i had expected to get the single elements i've selected back (which is actually true) but for some reason if i navigate the DOM again by XPath, it looks like that navigation is done on the table I've selected before and not in the selected table entry...

The solution is pretty straight forward, just start the DOM navigation one step higher and select the containing element first with XPath..

`var Id = elements[i].FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id, 'row_task_')][" + (i+1).ToString() + "]/td[3]/a")).Text;`